# How do I enable forbidden characters on google firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I enable forbidden characters on google firebase? ('.','#','$','[',']') I want to allow signing up using an email for my database but, because of this, I can't. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase keys in the Realtime Databse cannot contain those characters and there's no way to alter that behavior. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree)

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a
> maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII
> control characters 0-31 or 127. You cannot use ASCII control
> characters in the values themselves, either.

Firestore also has some requirements from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields)

```
Must be valid UTF-8 characters
Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
Cannot contain a forward slash (/)
Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
Cannot match the regular expression __.*__
(for documentIds) If you import Datastore entities into a Firestore database, numeric entity IDs are exposed as __id[0-9]+__
```

A lot of people when just getting started with Firebase have the tendency to want to store users by their email address

```
users
   jay@example.com
       name: "asdadsa"
```

but there's an inhenent issue with that strategy; you'll end up storing a reference to that user all over your database and you would then use the email as that reference

```
my_friends
   jay@example.com: true
```

or

```
people_I_know
   0: jay@example.com
```

etc.

But... Email addresses change if that happens you would have to not only delete the main users node (node keys cannot be changed) and then re-write it, you would also have to change every single occurrence of that email in your entire database!

The best practice is to disassociate node keys (documentsId's) from the data they contain

```
users
   uid_0 //a users uid or a randomly generated firebase id
     name: "Jay"
     email: "jay@example.com"
```

then you would store the uid or generated id as the reference instead of the email which makes changing the email address a snap since it won't affect any other nodes

```
my_friends
   uid_0: true
```

and

```
people_I_know
   0: uid_0
```

So, to answer the question, users will sign up using their email address which will create their user account in Firebase with an associated uid. Store other user information *by that users uid* in the Realtime Database or Firestore instead of their email.